# Why does this sequence of pointer operations cause an error?

Tags: c, pointers, free

Why does the (admittedly esoteric) pointer manipulation below cause the following error:

`*** Error in /home/ubuntu/workspace/Project 3/Debug/Project 3': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffffffd7c0 ***`

```
    int *intPointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *intPointer = 1;
    int intArray[] = { *intPointer };
    int *intPointer2 = &intArray[0];
    free(intPointer2);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value assigned to `intPointer2` is a pointer to the first element in `intArray`.  This array was allocated on the stack, so attempting to `free` it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can only `free` memory that was returned by `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc`. The fact that the first (and only) element in this array contains a copy of *the value pointed to by `intPointer`* (not a copy of the value of `intPointer`) doesn't matter.

Only calling `free(intPointer)` would work.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `&intArray[0]` to `free`, but you didn't get it from `malloc` so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: But I'm storying an integer that I did malloc in the array?

Comment: You're storing a copy of the malloc'd int. The copy isn't malloc'd.

Comment: If I stored `intPointer` in the array and then set `intPointer2 = intArray[0]` would the free on `intPointer2` work?

Comment: Yes (if it's an `int*` array). In that case `intArray[0]` is the same value that you got from `malloc` so passing it to `free` is ok.